Azure AD - keep user signed in without token cache
I have a react application that use Azure SSO for login. Due to security reason, we have to clear the browser storage which cached id token, access token and refresh token issued from Azure AD.
Now after 1 hour, the application will prompt Network Error.
From my understanding (after reading the doc), the cache token is used to acquire new access token silently when the existing is about to/ has expired, so that the user is not interrupted/ need to re-login again.
Is there other way to achieve the same result without the cached token? If not, how to detect the expired token and logout user, instead of prompting Network error?
Here my code in 
const App: FC = () => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
  const [account, setAccount] = useState<AccountInfo | null>(accounts && accounts[0] || null);
  const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
  const [msalAccessToken, setMsalAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const requestProfileData = async () => {
    // Silently acquires an access token which is then attached to a request for MS Graph data
    // acquireTokenSilent() will handle expired token automatically
    instance.acquireTokenSilent({
      scopes: ['User.Read'],
      account: accounts[0]
    }).then(async response => {
      setAccount(response.account);
      setAccessToken(response.idToken);
      setMsalAccessToken(response.accessToken);
      sessionStorage.clear();
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err.message);
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (accounts.length) {
      requestProfileData();
    }
  },[]);
}


To avoid caching tokens, you can use sessionStorage as a cache location. This will store tokens only for the duration of the page session and clear them when the tab or window is closed.

@DasariKamali due to security concern, we are not allowed to use sessionStorage either.

The below code manages user login and clears the session storage. It also handles token expiration by logging the user out if the token can't be renewed automatically.
I used sessionStorage.clear(), which removes all the stored data from the browser. The app won't be able to renew the token quietly. This means that after the token expires, the user will have to log in again.
App.tsx :
import React, { useEffect, useState, FC } from 'react';
import { useMsal } from '@azure/msal-react';
import { AccountInfo } from '@azure/msal-browser'; 
import AuthButton from './AuthButton';
import { authConfig } from './authConfig';

const App: FC = () => {
    const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();
    const [account, setAccount] = useState<AccountInfo | null>(accounts && accounts[0] || null);
    const [accessToken, setAccessToken] = useState<string | null>(null);

    const requestProfileData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await instance.acquireTokenSilent({
                scopes: ['User.Read'],
                account: accounts[0],
            });
            setAccount(response.account);
            setAccessToken(response.accessToken);
            sessionStorage.clear();

            const expirationTime = response.expiresOn 
                ? response.expiresOn.getTime() - Date.now() - 60000 
                : 0;
            if (expirationTime > 0) {
                setTimeout(() => {
                    handleTokenExpiry();
                }, expirationTime);
            } else {
                handleTokenExpiry();
            }
        } catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof Error) {
                console.error('Token acquisition error:', err.message);
            } else {
                console.error('Unknown error during token acquisition');
            }
            handleTokenExpiry(); 
        }
    };
    const handleTokenExpiry = () => {
        instance.logoutRedirect({
            postLogoutRedirectUri: authConfig.auth.redirectUri,
        });
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        if (accounts.length) {
            requestProfileData();
        }
    }, []);
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <h1>MSAL React App</h1>
                {accounts.length === 0 ? (
                    <AuthButton msalInstance={instance} />
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <p>Welcome, {accounts[0]?.username || 'User'}</p> {/* Use accounts[0].username */}
                        <button onClick={handleTokenExpiry}>Logout</button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}
export default App;

AuthButton.tsx :
import React from 'react';
import { IPublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';

interface AuthButtonProps {
    msalInstance: IPublicClientApplication;
}
const AuthButton: React.FC<AuthButtonProps> = ({ msalInstance }) => {
    const login = async () => {
        try {
            await msalInstance.loginPopup({
                scopes: ['openid', 'profile', 'user.read'],
                prompt: 'select_account',
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Login error:', error);
        }
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={login}>Login</button>
        </div>
    );
}
export default AuthButton;

index.tsx :
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { PublicClientApplication } from '@azure/msal-browser';
import { MsalProvider } from '@azure/msal-react';
import App from './App';
import { authConfig } from './authConfig';

const msalInstance = new PublicClientApplication(authConfig);
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <MsalProvider instance={msalInstance}>
            <App />
        </MsalProvider>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);

authConfig.ts :
export const authConfig = {
    auth: {
        clientId: '<clientID>',
        authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/<>tenantID',
        redirectUri: 'http://localhost:3000',
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage', 
        storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
    system: {
        allowNativeBroker: false,
    },
};

Output :
I got the below output and clicked on the Login button to log in.

I successfully logged in and clicked on the Logout button to log out.

I selected my account for logout and successfully logged out.


thanks for the sample, I also cleared the sessionStorage after successful login, but somehow the setTimeOut does not log me out near the token expiration. Does it work at your side?

I can log out by clicking the logout button, which automatically removes my account from the browser.
